# AWS CloudFormation EC2 UserData - Using an "!If"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating a .bashrc file in the UserData portion of my CloudFormation Template

```
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
```

At this point, I want to use one of two statements based on a condition.  Either

```
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            echo "export JOIN_STR=${ExistingJoinString}" >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
```

or

```
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            echo "export JOIN_STR=${CRDBIPNode01.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress},${CRDBIPNode02.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress},${CRDBIPNode03.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress}" >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
```

I already have a conditional defined:

```
Conditions: 
  UseNewJoinString: !Equals [!Ref ExistingJoinString, NONE]
```

Does anyone know of a way to use an "!If" statement, or any other hack I can use to control which statement ends up in my .bashrc.  Something like this:

```
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            !If
              - UseNewJoinString
              -
                echo "export JOIN_STR=${CRDBIPNode01.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress},${CRDBIPNode02.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress},${CRDBIPNode03.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress}" >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
              -
                echo "export JOIN_STR=${ExistingJoinString}" >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
```

Thanks in advance for help and insights.

Comment: Have not tried this, but maybe `!If [UseNewJoinString, "export A=abc", "export A=xyz"]`

Comment: @jarmod, that didn't seem to work... but thanks for the idea... sometimes that leads to the best answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently learning CloudFormation and do not know all the tricks but would using a macro to modify the template be a possible solution?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/macros-example.html

Comment: Thanks Marko.  That's more complexity than I was hoping to add, but I'm going to accept your answer, since it is probably the only path I can see that will get me to where I'm going.

Comment: Thanks. I saw behind this link (https://www.singlestoneconsulting.com/blog/cloudformation-mapping-and-conditionals-making-your-templates-more-universal/) an example of If function inside UserData which looks very similar to what @jarmod proposed above. Perhaps it is possible to do the trick in CFn template after all.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to embed the "if" statement directly into my .bashrc

```
            echo "if [ '${ExistingJoinString}' = 'NONE' ]; then"  >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
            echo "  export JOIN_STR=${CRDBIPNode01.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress},${CRDBIPNode02.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress},${CRDBIPNode03.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress}" >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
            echo "else"  >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
            echo "  export JOIN_STR=${ExistingJoinString}" >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
            echo "fi"  >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
```

Not very happy with this solution, but it works.  Still looking for better ideas.